# How do i solve 'function does not return a value on all code paths'

Tags: vb.net

I have researched and read everything I can from questions on here,however nothing I have tried has solved the issue. The function is meant to output a letter grade to the application.  Here is the code for the class and function for better clarity.

```
Public Class Coursegrade
'names private veriables 
Private _Score1 As Integer
Private _Score2 As Integer
Private _Score3 As Integer
Private Letter_grade As String
'gets and returns each veriable
'for application use
Public Property Grade As String
    Get
        Return Letter_grade
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value > String.Empty Then
            Letter_grade = value
        Else
            Letter_grade = String.Empty
        End If
    End Set
End Property
Public Property TestScore1 As Integer
    Get
        Return _Score1
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value > 0 Then
            _Score1 = value
        Else
            _Score1 = 0
        End If
    End Set
End Property


Property TestScore2 As Integer
    Get
        Return _Score2
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value > 0 Then
            _Score2 = value
        Else
            _Score2 = 0
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Property TestScore3 As Integer
    Get
        Return _Score3
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If value > 0 Then
            _Score3 = value
        Else
            _Score3 = 0
        End If
    End Set
End Property

'starts veriables of at 0
Public Sub New()
    _Score1 = 0
    _Score2 = 0
    _Score3 = 0
End Sub
'calculates the adverage
Public Function Gettotal() As Integer
    Return _Score1 + _Score2 + _Score3
End Function


Public Function Give_letter_grade() As String
    Dim intTotal As Integer
    intTotal = Gettotal()

    'start your secletion
    If intTotal <= 270 AndAlso intTotal >= 300 Then
        Letter_grade = "A"
    ElseIf intTotal <= 240 AndAlso intTotal >= 269 Then
        Letter_grade = "B"
    ElseIf intTotal <= 210 AndAlso intTotal >= 239 Then
        Letter_grade = "C"
    ElseIf intTotal <= 180 AndAlso intTotal >= 290 Then
        Letter_grade = "D"
    ElseIf intTotal > 180 Then
        Letter_grade = "F"
    Else

        Letter_grade = ""
    End If
End Function
```

The error shows on the end function of give letter grade

Comment: How can `intTotal` ever be <270 and >300 at the same time?  Also vba is not the same as VB.NET.  Since that method (function) doesnt `Return` anything, you get the message

Comment: What is your expectation from doing this:  If value > String.Empty Then

Comment: I was intending for it to give the same output for that number range.

Comment: @the_lotus I was trying to use that as a null value to fix the issue.

Comment: Why value > String.Empty? string compare use value ISNOT Nothing,

Comment: You should take the [tour] to learn how SO works: you have 5 answers on your past questions but they are all still open.  Clicking the checkmark helps other users find good answers.  Reading [ask] might help avoid DVs on your posts as well.

Comment: doing <> would cause it to use the null value no matter what wouldn't it?

Comment: @catsrull  `value > String.Empty` needs to be `value <> String.Empty`. `If value <> String.Empty Then` means if value is **not** empty then do `Letter_grade = value` else assign `Letter_grade` to String.Empty. It wouldn't always use null value no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function Give_letter_grade() As String
Dim intTotal As Integer
intTotal = Gettotal()

'start your secletion
If intTotal <= 300 AndAlso intTotal >= 270 Then
    Letter_grade = "A"
ElseIf intTotal <= 269 AndAlso intTotal >= 240 Then
    Letter_grade = "B"
ElseIf intTotal <= 239 AndAlso intTotal >= 210 Then
    Letter_grade = "C"
ElseIf intTotal < 210 AndAlso intTotal >= 180 Then
    Letter_grade = "D"
ElseIf intTotal < 180 Then
    Letter_grade = "F"
Else

    Letter_grade = ""
End If

Return Letter_grade '<--- you are missing the 'Return' statement
End Function
```

Comment: @catsrull You need to mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question

Comment: Thanks for also explaining  everything i was doing wrong and not being rude about  not making it